# How do I use jQuery replaceWith correctly

Tags: jquery, html

here is my menu code :-

```
<div class="menu">
 <ul>
   <li><a href="http://domain.com/">Home</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I want replace it using `.replaceWith` to be :-

```
<div class="menu">
 <ul class="something">
   <li><a href="http://domain.com/">Home</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I tried something like this : -

```
$('<div class="menu"><ul>').replaceWith('<div class="menu"><ul class="something">' + $(this).text() + '</ul></div>');
```

But it's not working

What is the correct code for this replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference I'm seeing is just the class of `<ul class="something">`.

Can't you just `addClass()` to it?

```
$('.menu ul').addClass('something');
```

Comment: Just one note: using `$('div.menu ul')` is going to be a bit quicker than `$('.menu ul')`.  Purely class-based selectors are among the slower jquery selectors.  The fastest option, of course, is to add an id to the element and use an id-based selector.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a jquery object using straight html code, it doesn't find matches for that code on the page; instead it creates a new element based on that html and wraps it in a jquery object.  Consequently you can replace it all you like and it won't affect your page.

You need to first find the element on the page using jquery selectors (`$("div.menu ul")`) and then do something to it:

```
$("div.menu ul").addClass("something");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it:

```
    $("ul").replaceWith("<ul class='something'><li><a href='http://domain.com/'>Home</a></li></ul>");
```

it works correctly..
Maybe value of attribute have to separated with single quote and syntax start and end with double quote..